# how to remove data bounded Dropdown list item on page load?

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, listitem, databound

i have a Drop-down list which is data bounded from a table
and i want to remove an item from it on page load, but the problem is nothing is happening from this piece of code:

**on page load:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ListItem itemToRemove = DropDownList1.Items.FindByText("compiler"); //just want to remove this value
    if (itemToRemove != null)
    {
        DropDownList1.Items.Remove(itemToRemove);
    }
}

**dropdownlist code on aspx page**:

<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1"  AppendDataBoundItems="true" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="qpname" DataValueField="qpname" Height="16px" Width="116px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True">
  <Items>
   <asp:ListItem Text="Select" Value="" />
   </Items>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

**the sqldata source code on aspx page:**

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:projectConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [qpname] FROM [A1_quespapers]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Note : dropdownlist is displaying the all bounded values including value to be deleted (compiler) -
[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMtYQ.png)

Comment: try to place your code in !isPostback

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `AppendDataBoundItems="False"` and set `DataSource` in PageLoad event. Next you will be able to remove your `Item`

Change `DropDownList` like this

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1"  AppendDataBoundItems="false" runat="server"  DataTextField="qpname" DataValueField="qpname" Height="16px" Width="116px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True">
```

Add DataSource and Remove item using `FindByText()` method

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    DropDownList1.DataSource = SqlDataSource1;
    DropDownList1.DataBind()

    ListItem itemToRemove = DropDownList1.Items.FindByText("compiler");   
    if (itemToRemove != null)
    {
        DropDownList1.Items.Remove(itemToRemove);
    }
}
```

Comment: or set `DropDownList1.DataSource = null;` then reassign when wanting to bind to a different DataSource would work too..

Answer (score 0):

You can try removing at ***PreRender*** event.

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ListItem itemToRemove = DropDownList1.Items.FindByText("compiler"); //just want to remove this value
    if (itemToRemove != null)
    {
        DropDownList1.Items.Remove(itemToRemove);
    }
}
```